# Java Hibernate java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value did not match expected type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

In Game entity i have :

`private Set<GameGenre> genres = new HashSet<>();`

I wrote custom query that will filter games by genre id. When i hardcode genre id in query it works :

```
@Query("select new com.twognation.hub.dto.GameDTO(game.id, game.name, game.active, game.description, game.coverImage, game.logo, game.backgroundImage, game.featuredImage, game.characterImage, game.smallCoverImage, count(tournament.id) as tournamentCount) from Game game left join Tournament tournament on game.id=tournament.game inner join game.genres genres where lower(game.name) like CONCAT('%', :name, '%') and genres IN (1301) group by game.id order by tournamentCount desc, game.id")
```

But when i try to pass list of ids :

```
@Query("select new com.twognation.hub.dto.GameDTO(game.id, game.name, game.active, game.description, game.coverImage, game.logo, game.backgroundImage, game.featuredImage, game.characterImage, game.smallCoverImage, count(tournament.id) as tournamentCount) from Game game left join Tournament tournament on game.id=tournament.game inner join game.genres genres where lower(game.name) like CONCAT('%', :name, '%') and genres IN (:genres) group by game.id order by tournamentCount desc, game.id")
    Page<GameDTO> findAllOrderByTournamentCountAndGenreFilter(@Param("name") String name, @Param("genres") String genres, Pageable page);
```

i get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1301] did not match expected type [com.twognation.hub.domain.GameGenre (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:492)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 172 common frames omitted
```

Game entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "game")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "cover_image")
    private String coverImage;

    @Column(name = "logo")
    private String logo;

    @Column(name = "background_image")
    private String backgroundImage;

    @Column(name = "featured_image")
    private String featuredImage;

    @Column(name = "character_image")
    private String characterImage;

    @Column(name = "small_cover_image")
    private String smallCoverImage;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "game_genres",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="games_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="genres_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<GameGenre> genres = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be `and genres.genreId IN (:genres)`.

```
@Query("select new com.twognation.hub.dto.GameDTO(game.id, game.name, game.active, game.description, game.coverImage, game.logo, game.backgroundImage, game.featuredImage, game.characterImage, game.smallCoverImage, count(tournament.id) as tournamentCount) from Game game left join Tournament tournament on game.id=tournament.game inner join game.genres genres where lower(game.name) like CONCAT('%', :name, '%') and genres.genreId IN (:genres) group by game.id order by tournamentCount desc, game.id")
Page<GameDTO> findAllOrderByTournamentCountAndGenreFilter(@Param("name") String name, @Param("genres") String genres, Pageable page);
```

`genres` is the entity and `genreId` is the variable name mapped to genre_id(I guess).

**UPDATE:**

After OP added the entity class.

When passing as `Param` you are explicitly mentioning it to be `String` which causes `IllegalArgumentException` as the entity expects `HashSet<GameGenre>`.

So the method signature should be,

`Page<GameDTO> findAllOrderByTournamentCountAndGenreFilter(@Param("name") String name, @Param("genres") HashSet<GameGenre> genres, Pageable page);`

and you should pass the `Param` as,

```
GameGenre gameGenre = new GameGenre();
gameGenre.setGenreId(1301);

HashSet<GameGenre> genres = new HashSet<GameGenre>();
geners.add(gameGenre);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how does it work with hardcoded id line in my example ?

Comment: can you post your entity classes ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to pass an object of the type GameGenre and not a String. Maybe also a Collection of GameGenre objects.